# Classical 3-body problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, specific-reference, newtonian-gravity

There is a formulation of the classical [3-body Newtonian problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem) reducing this problem to 6 equations (e.g. http://www.3bproblem.blogspot.com). I would like to know where can I find a discussion or demo of this setting.
Any examples of other non-trivial frames for this problem are also welcome, i.e. others than the center of mass frame in 9 equations.

Answer (score 1):

A general discussion -- including introductions to different formulations -- of the three-body problem can be found in M. Gutzwiller's [Chaos in Classical and Quantum Mechanics](http://books.google.de/books/about/Chaos_in_Classical_and_Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=fnO3XYYpU54C&redir_esc=y), Chapters 4 and 5. The references therein may be more useful than the text itself.